# Excel 2016 AddIn VSTO workbook project cannot be created

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vsto

I'm trying to create Excel 2016 VSTO workbook project but i'm getting the following message:

"The Project cannot be created."

I have

Visual Studio Professional 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

.NET version 4.6.2

Office 2016 64bit latest version

I've tried also to revert the version back to:

October 4, 2016
Version 1609 (Build 7369.2024)

September 26, 2016
Version 1608 (Build 7341.2035)
but it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Eran

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is a bug that stops this working: (I can't make it work either).

I did see a post that said the fix was included in Excel build 7823.1000, (currently on Insider Fast, don't know when it will appear on Insider Slow).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reverting back the office version to version 7167.2060 solved the problem.

Eran